# .ToSelectList parameters error to display in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble figuring out what parameters to pass in my `.ToSelectList()` so i can display my results in a dropdown list box. I have two `IQueryable` items and i want to display the results together in one dropdown. I don't have to compare and match it is simply grap and display. A sample of how the results look like is:

```
Teacher
Doctor
Nurse
Engineer
Jack Smith
Tim Jones
Jill Jack
```

Here is how my code looks so far:

```
IQueryable<Report_JobResults> jobs=
            _jobsReportRepository.summaryGetJob().OrderBy(o=>o.JobName);

IQueryable<Report_nameResult> users =
           _nameReportRepository.summaryGetName().OrderBy(n => n.FirstName).ThenBy(
               n => n.LastName);

//Here is where i display results into a dropdown box.

view.Results=jobs.Select(o => o.jobId).ToList().Union(users.Select(u =>     u.userId).ToList()).ToSelectList();
```

I am not sure what the parameters will be in the `.ToSelectList()`

Help will be very much appreciated. :)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
var results = jobs.Select(o => o.jobId).Union(users.Select(u => u.userId))
    .Select( i => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = i,
        Value = i
    };
```

and use `results` for in `Html.DropDownListFor()`.

Comment: Thanks, i will go ahead and try this but just wondering what is 'i' and what is it doing?

Comment: `i` represents each element in `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`

Comment: I tried this but i am just getting the numbers of the items in the dropdown not the actual value.

Comment: Then in the select try using the name attribute instead of jobid and userid.

Comment: Also one more question - if i wanted to check what the user has selected whether it was a jobName or a UserName what could i use to tell which type was selected to return different data according to selection.